# Are processes launched by elevated processes themselves elevated?

Tags: windows, uac

I have a program that launches a browser window when a user performs certain actions. My program requires Administrator access (i.e. must be launched via "Run as Administrator" or have requestedElevationLevel set to requireAdministrator in its manifest file in Vista or Win7).

I am worried that the browser will inherit the elevation level of the parent process; that is, I'm concerned the browser will also be launched with Administrator elevation. Is this correct? If so, is there any way to prevent this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

UAC can be a rather complex concept to wrap your head around. Generally speaking, a child process inherits its access token from the parent process. However, this only occurs if both processes have the same **`integrity level`**:

> Each application that requires the
>   administrator access token must prompt
>   the administrator for consent. The one
>   exception is the relationship that
>   exists between parent and child
>   processes. Child processes inherit the
>   user access token from the parent
>   process. Both the parent and child
>   processes, however, must have the same
>   integrity level.

Integrity levels depend on a variety of things, but generally speaking, a web browser is a *`low integrity`* application, and will likely require an additional UAC prompt if it tries to do any operation requiring a higher level of privilege:

> Windows 7 protects processes by
>   marking their integrity levels.
>   Integrity levels are measurements of
>   trust. A "high" integrity application
>   is one that performs tasks that modify
>   system data, such as a disk
>   partitioning application, while a
>   "low" integrity application is one
>   that performs tasks that could
>   potentially compromise the operating
>   system, such as a Web browser.
>   Applications with lower integrity
>   levels cannot modify data in
>   applications with higher integrity
>   levels.

If you wish to learn more about UAC, the following articles are a good resource:

- [UAC Processes and Interactions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd835561(WS.10).aspx)
- [UAC Architecture](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd835540(WS.10).aspx)

Comment: TLDR: yes, they are elevated if they are a child process with the same integrity level. **But they are likely not to be**

Comment: Read his full answer, it's highly relevant to the OP. He is specifically concerned about a web browser inheriting elevated status, which as jrista explains, it probably won't be inherited for a browser.

Comment: Thanks for emphasizing that @nhinkle, edited my comment appropriately

Answer (score 0):

You are correct. Any process that spawns a child process inherits it's security context (admin or not) by default.

I'm not sure there's a way around this without control of this program's source code (but I may be wrong).